# Robotium Get Text for the ListView

Tags: android, robotium

1: I have a List view as below:

```
sort
game
play
home
```

How can we get all the Text of the above List either One by one or all in robotium.

2: Is there any way we are able to create a file in SDcard(Emulator).

Please suggest a way.

Answer (score 1):

For the first Question, My solution is:

```
RelativeLayout rowItem;
            for (int i = 0; i < listView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                rowItem = (RelativeLayout) listView.getChildAt(i);
                TextView tv = (TextView) rowItem
                        .findViewById(R.id.my_tv);
                        String text = tv.getText();

            }
```

Second Question:
Definitely, You can

Answer (score 0):

You can use solo.getCurrentTextViews(View parent) where the parent is the list.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the second question try this one

```
Context ctx = getInstrumentation().getContext();
AssetManager assetManager = ctx.getAssets();
File a = ctx.getFilesDir();
a.createNewFile();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution how to get unique names from ListView items:

```
//check if ListView contains elements by getting ListView size
int index = 0;
int elemCount = 0;
ListView listView = (ListView) solo.getCurrentListViews().get(index);
elemCount = listView.getAdapter() != null ? listView.getAdapter().getCount() : 0;

//Creating a Map of existing elements 
Map<String, Integer> namesMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

//Going through the list of elements and mapping it's names
for (int i = 0; i < elemCount ; i++) {

  String name = ((StructureElement) listView.getAdapter().getItem(i)).getName();
  namesMap.put(name , i);

}

Log.i("Names and indexes are : " + namesMap);
```

Just create additional method which will return `namesMap` in case you want to get ListItem index by it's name and "vice versa" if you want to get ListItem name by it's index.

Feel free to reuse it)

Comment: What is getCurrentListViews() it doesn't seem to exist in solo